# Error 1064 when running CREATE TABLE script

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a SQL script to add tables to my database and keep getting error 1064. Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE 'Bookings' (
'Booking_id' INTEGER(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'Arrival_Date' date(8) CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
'Departure_Date' date(8) CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
'Registrants_ID' INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
'Accomodation_ID' INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('Booking_ID'),
KEY 'Accomodation_ID' ('Accomodation_ID'),
KEY 'Registrants_ID' ('Registrants_ID'),
CONSTRAINT 'bookings_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('Accomodation_ID') REFERENCES 'Accommodation' ('Accomodation_ID')
CONSTRAINT 'bookings_ibfk_2' FOREIGN KEY ('Registrants_ID') REFERENCES 'Registrants' ('Registrants_ID')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the ' to the column names.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should use datetime for Arrival_Date etc,

current_timestamp give : `2015-02-18 15:34:24`

current_date:  `2015-02-18`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a default value if you specify `DEFAULT`.

E.g.

```
'Registrants_ID' INTEGER(10) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
'Accomodation_ID' INTEGER(10) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
```

Also you should be using backticks ( ` ) instead of single quotes ( ' ) around field/table/index names.

Also you cannot make a date field default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. And if you want a timestamp field to default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you need the `DEFAULT` keyword. e.g.: `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: `DEFAULT` *must* be used if the column has the `NOT NULL` attribute